# Complex plane sets - domain |Argz | < pi/4

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Why is the following complex set a domain:

|Arg z | < pi/ 4 if Arg z = 0 is not defined, so there is no polygonal path between the two quadrants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The argument of zero is not defined, i.e. $\arg 0$ is not defined.
- There are many $z$ for which $\arg z = 0$, e.g. all of the positive real axis.

Writing $z = r\!\operatorname{e}^{i\theta}$, the origin has $r = 0$ and so all possible values of $\theta$ correspond to the the origin. That's why we say that the argument of the origin is not well-define; it takes every possible value! Moreover, the change of coordinates $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ fails to be a diffeomorphism when $r=0$, i.e. when $x=y=0.$

Comment: Oh right only z=0 is undefined, thanks

Comment: @DJ_ No worries. Glad to help.

Remember to up-vote answers that you find helpful by clicking the "up arrow" and to pick the most helpful answer by clicking the "tick".